# How to ignore file with Patch element?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am using Wix 3.5 to create Patch. I don't want one file to be updated even though it changed. How do I define this in the `<Patch>` element ?

I know `<PatchCreation>` has `UpgradeFile` element that is used for this but I'm not sure how is this done in the `<Patch>` element?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you go the pure-WiX way of patch creation (I mean, with `<Patch>` element), you should think the other way around: **think of what you want it to include, instead of what you don't**.

One of the direct children of `<Patch>` element - the `<PatchFamily>` element may contain a number of references, e.g. `ComponentRef`, `FeatureRef`, etc. If you don't mention anything inside the `<PatchFamily>`, it will include all the differences by default. Otherwise, it will just include what you instruct it to include.

It makes sense to me, hope you can configure it the way you'd like.